# Add Triangle shape from Popup Panel to a point

Tags: apache-flex, dictionary, geometry, shapes

I am trying to add a trianlge shape from the Popup "Address Details" to the pin point I have on the map. To try and give it the effect that the Address Details is coming from the pin point. I tried messing around with some code from Abode to get a triangle to show up but all it did was make my Address Details disappear. This is the site from Abode I tried using. http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=Drawing_Vector_Graphics_4.html

If anyone could help me figure out how to do the triangle or maybe another suggestion for what I am trying to accomplish it would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

EDIT: Showing code I have tried

```
    // green triangle, starting at point 200, 0
triangle.graphics.beginFill(0x00FF00);
triangle.graphics.moveTo(200 + triangleHeight/2, 0);
triangle.graphics.lineTo(200 + triangleHeight, triangleHeight);
triangle.graphics.lineTo(200, triangleHeight);
triangle.graphics.lineTo(200 + triangleHeight/2, 0);

this.addChild(triangle);

    var line:Graphics;
                        line.moveTo(100,100);
                        line.lineTo(200,200);
```

Above are the two different things I tried. I didn't try to match the points exactly yet just trying to get it to display first. But If I added any of this I never saw a shape, didn't get any errors, and my Address Detail Panel would simple show the blue header and nothing more.

This is what I would like to attempt to do.
[image]

Comment: Show us what you've tried.  If possible, you may also want to include a screenshot of what you want the final result to look like.

Comment: added more detail as to what I have tried ad what I would like for it to look like